# Scapy calculate the total packet length for each ip address

Tags: python, scapy

The current code below is able to read pcap file and extract the destination IP addresses and the size of the packet

What I do want to do is just count each destination IP and have the packet total for each destination IP address

There are several other ways to load a pcap file using Scapy but they load everything in memory e.g rdpcap although even the sniff function takes too long on a large pcap file this seems the best solution in that it bypasses any analysis of the payload

Input

```
dic = {}

IP.payload_guess = []

#ips = set((p[IP].dst,p[IP].len) for p in PcapReader(file) if IP in p)
ips = set(p[IP].dst for p in PcapReader(file) if IP in p)

for ip in ips:
    list_ips.append(ip)
    dic[ip] = 1
```

Ouput

```
('192.168.1.238', 658)
('255.255.255.255', 328)
('89.30.121.150', 109)
('89.30.121.150', 270)
('192.168.1.238', 417)
('89.30.121.150', 378)
('89.30.121.150', 316)
('89.30.121.150', 287)
('192.168.1.1', 66)
('89.30.121.150', 48)
('89.30.121.150', 262)
('89.30.121.150', 107)
('89.30.121.150', 498)
('89.30.121.150', 40)
('192.168.1.238', 426)
('192.168.1.238', 328)
('89.30.121.150', 319)
('192.168.1.238', 48)
('192.168.1.238', 478)
('89.30.121.150', 45)
('192.168.1.238', 44)
('89.30.121.150', 239)
('89.30.121.150', 186)
('192.168.1.238', 884)
('192.168.1.238', 40)
('89.30.121.150', 552)
('89.30.121.150', 227)
('89.30.121.150', 318)
('89.30.121.150', 223)
('0.0.0.0', 328)
('89.30.121.150', 44)
('192.168.1.238', 82)
('192.168.1.238', 584)
('89.30.121.150', 238)
('192.168.1.238', 65)
('89.30.121.150', 379)
('89.30.121.150', 438)
```

As you can see from the output the destination IP address and the second column is the packet len(I need the total packet len for each IP address)

I am assuming I have to use map somehow